# Variable number of columns in each row (css only solution)?

Tags: css, dynamic, css-grid

How can I force an item to expand to fill the whole row or column when there's only one item in that row or column?

My CSS:

```
.squareThumbnailContainer {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 1fr 1fr); 
  grid-template-rows:  repeat(auto-fit, 1fr, 1fr); 
  gap: 0px 0px; 
  grid-template-areas: 
    ". ."
    ". ."; 
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}

.smallSquareThumbnailHelper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.smallSquareThumbnail {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I know there's a max of 4 items.

My HTML (vue.js template)

```
     <div
          class="squareThumbnailContainer"
        >
          <div
            v-if="index <= 3"
            class="smallSquareThumbnailHelper"
            v-for="(img, index) in images"
          >
            <img
              class="smallSquareThumbnail"
              :src="img.imageUrl"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
```

this is my current result. It works when there's just one item, but not when there are 2 or 3 items...

[image]

UPDATE2: almost there thanks to @thpbaxxter , but can't make it work for two items.... if I use `.smallSquareThumbnailHelper:nth-child(3):last-child {grid-column: span 2;}` i get this result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grid-column: span 2;` on the last/third image to fill two column widths.

```css
.squareThumbnailContainer {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px; 
  grid-template-areas: 
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 1em;
}

.smallSquareThumbnailHelper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.smallSquareThumbnail {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}

.smallSquareThumbnail:nth-child(3):last-child {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.smallSquareThumbnail:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
.smallSquareThumbnail:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ .smallSquareThumbnail {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="squareThumbnailContainer">
  <div class="smallSquareThumbnail" style="background: red;"></div>
</div>

<div class="squareThumbnailContainer">
  <div class="smallSquareThumbnail" style="background: red;"></div>
  <div class="smallSquareThumbnail" style="background: green;"></div>
</div>

<div class="squareThumbnailContainer">
  <div class="smallSquareThumbnail" style="background: red;"></div>
  <div class="smallSquareThumbnail" style="background: green;"></div>
  <div class="smallSquareThumbnail" style="background: blue;"></div>
</div>

<div class="squareThumbnailContainer">
  <div class="smallSquareThumbnail" style="background: red;"></div>
  <div class="smallSquareThumbnail" style="background: green;"></div>
  <div class="smallSquareThumbnail" style="background: blue;"></div>
  <div class="smallSquareThumbnail" style="background: yellow;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @thpbaxxter but It's not quite that I'm looking for.  I can't attribute the class I want to the right item because it's the HTML is generated dynamically. I've updated my questions showing the results with your answer.

Comment: Thats what I thought, I updated the css rule to expand to `:nth-child(3):last-child`

Comment: Almost! Updated my question. Just missing the 2 items scenario! Notice I have  'smallSquareThumbnailHelper' wrapper helper...  also if i remove the values *". ." ". ."  in ` grid-template-areas: 
    ". ."
    ". .";`  it doesn't render

Comment: Oh ok, missed that you wanted the columns filled, too. Then add something like `.smallSquareThumbnail:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
 .smallSquareThumbnail:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ .smallSquareThumbnail`. Updated the snippet